# How to get WordPress Theme Customizer options in the REST API?

Tags: customization, rest-api

I am trying to work with the WordPress REST Api as a backend for a React application. But I don't understand how to get/fetch the customizer options (check this image for example -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1U93.jpg) of the theme? I know i can get posts with /wp/v2/posts but how do i get the customizer options? Any help appreciated.

Comment: There's no standard endpoint for retrieving Customizer/theme options, but you can create a custom endpoint - check details and examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for pointing me in the right direction @SallyCJ